# errors activating a typo3 8 extension

Tags: php, sql, typo3, typo3-8.x

At the moment I migrate typo3 6.2.31 Plugins to typo3 8.7.

I've made the changes that are required thate my extension works on 8.7.

But when I activate the extension I got this:

```
#1476171315: [SQL Error] line 0, col 254: Error: Expected NOT, NULL, DEFAULT, AUTO_INCREMENT, UNIQUE, PRIMARY, COMMENT, COLUMN_FORMAT, STORAGE or REFERENCES, got 'tstamp' in statement: CREATE TABLE tx_shopextension_domain_model_crontab ( uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment, pid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, workflow_strategie varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, verarbeitet tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL tstamp int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, crdate int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, cruser_id int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, deleted tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, hidden tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, starttime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, endtime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_oid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_wsid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_label varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL, t3ver_state tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_stage int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_count int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_tstamp int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, t3ver_move_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, sys_language_uid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, l10n_parent int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL, l10n_diffsource mediumblob, PRIMARY KEY (uid), KEY parent (pid), KEY t3ver_oid (t3ver_oid,t3ver_wsid), KEY language (l10n_parent,sys_language_uid) )
```

What could be the issue in this case?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the file ext_tables.sql you've the definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tx_shopextension_domain_model_crontab (
 uid int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 pid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 workflow_strategie varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 verarbeitet tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL
 tstamp int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 crdate int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 cruser_id int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 deleted tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 hidden tinyint(4) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 starttime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 endtime int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_oid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_wsid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_label varchar(255) DEFAULT '' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_state tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_stage int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_count int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_tstamp int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 t3ver_move_id int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 sys_language_uid int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 l10n_parent int(11) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
 l10n_diffsource mediumblob, PRIMARY KEY (uid),
 KEY parent (pid), KEY t3ver_oid (t3ver_oid,t3ver_wsid),
 KEY language (l10n_parent,sys_language_uid)
);
```

There after `verarbeitet tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL` the comma is missing.